# Error thrown calling Node.js net.createConnection

Tags: node.js

This question is related to: [Error in MySQL library for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js)

Node.js Version 5.12

I import the net library as follows:

var net = require('net');

An in my method this line throws and error:

const test = net.createConnection(3306, 'localhost');

**Error: _net2.default.createConnection is not a function**

Can anyone explain why I would get this error calling createConnection in "net"?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your `net` library is the built-in node.js library and not some other library?

Comment: I just installed node.js with the default options

Comment: Did you install anything else?  Any other modules?  Which version of node.js?

Comment: using node 5.12.. I also have express

Comment: Well, it's hard to say why it's doing that.  Probably something odd about your installation.  I would probably use the debugger to step into the `const test = net.createConnection(3306, 'localhost');` call and see where/why it's going haywire and if it goes through the expected `net` module.  Stepping through async operations is a bit more work, but it ultimately shows you exactly what is going on and why.

Comment: Answer is posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js

Comment: That answer says the problem was the OP was running the code in the browser.  Your question said you were running the code in Node.js.  So, is your question wrong?  Are you running it in the browser?  If you were running it in a browser and that was your problem, you may as well delete your question because it's misleading and unanswerable as written.