# How to send data from Node.js(webpack) to pure Node.js(express)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, webpack

I am getting data in a local storage of Webpack in JSON format. Node.js of Webpack is not allowing me to create a connection with MySQL. So, I am thinking if there is a way to send data to a backend(pure Node/Express server) like REST API.

I cannot use MySQL directly in Webpack node.js file

1.[ref stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js)

2.[ref GitHub](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/1780)

Below is my Webpack code I want save my localstorage data to database like MySQL, mongoDB.

```
import twitter from 'twitter-text';
import PDFJSAnnotate from '../';
import initColorPicker from './shared/initColorPicker';
/*import mysql from '../';
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "ali",
  password: "demopassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});*/
//var hummus = require('HummusJS/hummus');
const { UI } = PDFJSAnnotate;
const documentId = 'question.pdf';
let PAGE_HEIGHT;
let RENDER_OPTIONS = {
  documentId,
  pdfDocument: null,
  scale: parseFloat(localStorage.getItem(`${documentId}/scale`), 10) || 1.33,
  rotate: parseInt(localStorage.getItem(`${documentId}/rotate`), 10) || 0
};

PDFJSAnnotate.setStoreAdapter(new PDFJSAnnotate.LocalStoreAdapter());
PDFJS.workerSrc = './shared/pdf.worker.js';
//var annotationz = localStorage.getItem(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId + '/annotations') || [];
//console.log(annotationz);
// Render stuff
let NUM_PAGES = 0;
document.getElementById('content-wrapper').addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  let visiblePageNum = Math.round(e.target.scrollTop / PAGE_HEIGHT) + 1;
  let visiblePage = document.querySelector(`.page[data-page-number="${visiblePageNum}"][data-loaded="false"]`);
  if (visiblePage) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      UI.renderPage(visiblePageNum, RENDER_OPTIONS);
    });
  }
});

function render() {
  PDFJS.getDocument(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId).then((pdf) => {
    RENDER_OPTIONS.pdfDocument = pdf;

    let viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
    viewer.innerHTML = '';
    NUM_PAGES = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
    for (let i=0; i<NUM_PAGES; i++) {
      let page = UI.createPage(i+1);
      viewer.appendChild(page);
    }

    UI.renderPage(1, RENDER_OPTIONS).then(([pdfPage, annotations]) => {
      let viewport = pdfPage.getViewport(RENDER_OPTIONS.scale, RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate);
      PAGE_HEIGHT = viewport.height;
    });
  });
}
render();

// Text stuff
(function () {
  let textSize;
  let textColor;
 // let fontface;


  function initText() {
    let size = document.querySelector('.toolbar .text-size');
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 18, 24, 30, 36, 48, 60, 72, 96].forEach((s) => {
      size.appendChild(new Option (s, s));
    });

    /*let face = document.querySelector('.toolbar .font-face');
    ['fontGeorgiaSerif', 'fontPalatinoSerif', 'fontTimesSerif', 'Sans-Serif Fonts', 'fontArialSansSerif', 'fontComicSansMS', 'fontVerdanaSansMS', 'Monospace Fonts', 'fontCourierNew', 'fontLucidaConsole'].forEach((s) => {
      face.appendChild(new Option (s, s));
    });*/

    setText(
      localStorage.getItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/text/size`) || 10,
      localStorage.getItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/text/color`) || '#000000'
      //localStorage.getItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/text/face`) || 'fontGeorgiaSerif'
      // console.log(${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId});
    );

    initColorPicker(document.querySelector('.text-color'), textColor, function (value) {
      setText(textSize, value);
    });
  }

  function setText(size, color) {
    let modified = false;

    if (textSize !== size) {
      modified = true;
      textSize = size;
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/text/size`, textSize);
      document.querySelector('.toolbar .text-size').value = textSize;
    }

  /*  if (fontface !== face) {
      modified = true;
      fontface = face;
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/text/face`, fontface);
      document.querySelector('.toolbar .font-face').value = fontface;
    }*/

    if (textColor !== color) {
      modified = true;
      textColor = color;
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/text/color`, textColor);

      let selected = document.querySelector('.toolbar .text-color.color-selected');
      if (selected) {
        selected.classList.remove('color-selected');
        selected.removeAttribute('aria-selected');
      }

      selected = document.querySelector(`.toolbar .text-color[data-color="${color}"]`);
      if (selected) {
        selected.classList.add('color-selected');
        selected.setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
      }

    }

    if (modified) {
      UI.setText(textSize, textColor);
    }
  }

  function handleTextSizeChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value, textColor);
  }

  document.querySelector('.toolbar .text-size').addEventListener('change', handleTextSizeChange);

  initText();
})();

// Pen stuff
(function () {
  let penSize;
  let penColor;

  function initPen() {
    let size = document.querySelector('.toolbar .pen-size');
    for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
      size.appendChild(new Option(i+1, i+1));
    }

    setPen(
      localStorage.getItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/pen/size`) || 1,
      localStorage.getItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/pen/color`) || '#000000'
    );

    initColorPicker(document.querySelector('.pen-color'), penColor, function (value) {
      setPen(penSize, value);
    });
  }

  function setPen(size, color) {
    let modified = false;

    if (penSize !== size) {
      modified = true;
      penSize = size;
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/pen/size`, penSize);
      document.querySelector('.toolbar .pen-size').value = penSize;
    }

    if (penColor !== color) {
      modified = true;
      penColor = color;
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/pen/color`, penColor);

      let selected = document.querySelector('.toolbar .pen-color.color-selected');
      if (selected) {
        selected.classList.remove('color-selected');
        selected.removeAttribute('aria-selected');
      }

      selected = document.querySelector(`.toolbar .pen-color[data-color="${color}"]`);
      if (selected) {
        selected.classList.add('color-selected');
        selected.setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
      }
    }

    if (modified) {
      UI.setPen(penSize, penColor);
    }
  }

  function handlePenSizeChange(e) {
    setPen(e.target.value, penColor);
  }

  document.querySelector('.toolbar .pen-size').addEventListener('change', handlePenSizeChange);

  initPen();
})();

// Toolbar buttons
(function () {
  let tooltype = localStorage.getItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/tooltype`) || 'cursor';
  if (tooltype) {
    setActiveToolbarItem(tooltype, document.querySelector(`.toolbar button[data-tooltype=${tooltype}]`));
  }

  function setActiveToolbarItem(type, button) {
    let active = document.querySelector('.toolbar button.active');
    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove('active');

      switch (tooltype) {
        case 'cursor':
          UI.disableEdit();
          break;
        case 'draw':
          UI.disablePen();
          break;
        case 'text':
          UI.disableText();
          break;
        case 'point':
          UI.disablePoint();
          break;
        case 'area':
        case 'highlight':
        case 'strikeout':
          UI.disableRect();
          break;
      }
    }

    if (button) {
      button.classList.add('active');
    }
    if (tooltype !== type) {
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/tooltype`, type);
    }
    tooltype = type;

    switch (type) {
      case 'cursor':
        UI.enableEdit();
        break;
      case 'draw':
        UI.enablePen();
        break;
      case 'text':
        UI.enableText();
        break;
      case 'point':
        UI.enablePoint();
        break;
      case 'area':
      case 'highlight':
      case 'strikeout':
        UI.enableRect(type);
        break;
    }
  }

  function handleToolbarClick(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
      setActiveToolbarItem(e.target.getAttribute('data-tooltype'), e.target);
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('.toolbar').addEventListener('click', handleToolbarClick);
})();

// Scale/rotate
(function () {
  function setScaleRotate(scale, rotate) {
    scale = parseFloat(scale, 10);
    rotate = parseInt(rotate, 10);

    if (RENDER_OPTIONS.scale !== scale || RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate !== rotate) {
      RENDER_OPTIONS.scale = scale;
      RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate = rotate;

      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/scale`, RENDER_OPTIONS.scale);
      localStorage.setItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/rotate`, RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate % 360);

      render();
    }
  }

  function handleScaleChange(e) {
    setScaleRotate(e.target.value, RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate);
  }

  function handleRotateCWClick() {
    setScaleRotate(RENDER_OPTIONS.scale, RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate + 90);
  }

  function handleRotateCCWClick() {
    setScaleRotate(RENDER_OPTIONS.scale, RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate - 90);
  }

  document.querySelector('.toolbar select.scale').value = RENDER_OPTIONS.scale;
  document.querySelector('.toolbar select.scale').addEventListener('change', handleScaleChange);
  document.querySelector('.toolbar .rotate-ccw').addEventListener('click', handleRotateCCWClick);
  document.querySelector('.toolbar .rotate-cw').addEventListener('click', handleRotateCWClick);
})();

// Clear toolbar button
(function () {
  function handleClearClick(e) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear annotations?')) {
      for (let i=0; i<NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        document.querySelector(`div#pageContainer${i+1} svg.annotationLayer`).innerHTML = '';
      }

      localStorage.removeItem(`${RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId}/annotations`);
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('a.clear').addEventListener('click', handleClearClick);
})();

// Comment stuff
(function (window, document) {
  let commentList = document.querySelector('#comment-wrapper .comment-list-container');
  let commentForm = document.querySelector('#comment-wrapper .comment-list-form');
  let commentText = commentForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

  function supportsComments(target) {
    let type = target.getAttribute('data-pdf-annotate-type');
    return ['point', 'highlight', 'area'].indexOf(type) > -1;
  }

  function insertComment(comment) {
    let child = document.createElement('div');
    child.className = 'comment-list-item';
    child.innerHTML = twitter.autoLink(twitter.htmlEscape(comment.content));

    commentList.appendChild(child);
  }

  function handleAnnotationClick(target) {
    if (supportsComments(target)) {
      let documentId = target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-pdf-annotate-document');
      let annotationId = target.getAttribute('data-pdf-annotate-id');

      PDFJSAnnotate.getStoreAdapter().getComments(documentId, annotationId).then((comments) => {
        commentList.innerHTML = '';
        commentForm.style.display = '';
        commentText.focus();

        commentForm.onsubmit = function () {
          PDFJSAnnotate.getStoreAdapter().addComment(documentId, annotationId, commentText.value.trim())
            .then(insertComment)
            .then(() => {
              commentText.value = '';
              commentText.focus();
            });

          return false;
        };

        comments.forEach(insertComment);
      });
    }
  }

  function handleAnnotationBlur(target) {
    if (supportsComments(target)) {
      commentList.innerHTML = '';
      commentForm.style.display = 'none';
      commentForm.onsubmit = null;

      insertComment({content: 'No comments'});
    }
  }

  UI.addEventListener('annotation:click', handleAnnotationClick);
  UI.addEventListener('annotation:blur', handleAnnotationBlur);
})(window, document);
```

Comment: _Node.js of Webpack_???? Never heard of it.\ One question what is webpack?

Comment: @Jai https://hackernoon.com/full-stack-web-application-using-react-node-js-express-and-webpack-97dbd5b9d708

Comment: I know but you wrote it very confusingly.

Comment: I have not worked before with Webpack so, don't know much about it. I think is pure js loading by Webpack module of Node.js. I think I have to write AJAX for the JS FILE code I SHared above

Comment: Webpack is a bundling tool for transpiling latest javascript to es5 standard.

Comment: OK, then It is Pure JS running through Node Webpack. How to write AJAX for it.

Comment: Sorry for the answer but, any google search on "ajax request javascript" is going to give you the result. Or Jquery, it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple AJAX was working on the page because Webpack is a module bundler. Its main purpose is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser, yet it is also capable of transforming, bundling, or packaging [read more...](https://webpack.js.org/)

So in my case Node js was using Webpack module to load javascript in a browser. It is pure javascript. So I just implemented ajax on my javascript code and it is simply working like a REST API.