# React js connect to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

How do I connect my reactjs to mysql?
I already install mysql and I follow the common instruction to connect it but it doesn't work. It gets an error "TypeError: mysql.createConnection is not a function".

Here are my codes below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as mysql from 'mysql';

class Users extends Component {


    constructor(props){


        const mysql = require('mysql');

        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host: 'localhost',
          user: 'root',
          password: '',
          database: 'react_prac'
        });
        connection.connect();
         console.log(connection);


        super(props);
    }

    render() { 
        return (  
            <div>
                DB
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Users;
```

I also want to know if this is the right way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move important MySQL to the top of the import statements. May be require is not working for you

```
    import mysql from 'mysql';
```

And also make sure always super should be the first line in constructor

Updated code:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import mysql from 'mysql';
   class Users extends Component {
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           const connection = mysql.createConnection({
           host: 'localhost',
           user: 'root',
           password: '',
           database: 'react_prac'
        });
       connection.connect();
       console.log(connection);
    }

render() { 
    return (  
        <div>
            DB
        </div>
    );
   }
 }

 export default Users;
```

Update:

```
  It seems DB connection is not possible from front end. It should be done in the backend, for better understanding check this answer
```

[Error in MySQL library for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js)

Comment: error says "TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function".

Comment: this._socket = this.config.socketPath ? Net.createConnection(this.config.socketPath) : Net.createConnection(this.config.port, this.config.host); // Connect socket to connection domain

Comment: @vinceunggoy. The latest error is not related to mysql create connection. Looks like your original issue is resolved now

Comment: Yes, but it gets a new error. TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function

Comment: @vinceunggoy you can’t create MySQL connection in web browser I mean in react. It should be done only in Node backend module. Check this for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js

Comment: Hi sir Hemadri! the error is gone now. I already fixed it. thank you for your help! :)

Comment: How is that fixed?