# why .Net.createConnection doesn't work on a browser and how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to setup a database connection with my web-application (I'm using XAMPP - phpmyadmin).

In this milestone, I came across Node.js for the first time and managed to make the `require()` function to work by using `browserify`. This is my javascript file that is executed when clicking the Sign-Up button on the `register.php`.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var thisUser = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "admin1",
    password: "password",
    database: "db_mymindmapper"
});


------------- WORKS UNTIL HERE -------------

thisUser.connect(function(error){
    if(!error) {

        alert("NODE CONNECTED TO MYSQL SERVER");
        var sql = "INSERT INTO student_demographics (first_name) VALUES ('YOU DID IT MF')";

        thisUser.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if(!err){
                alert("result = " + result);

            }else{
                throw err;
            }
        });

    }else{
        throw error;
    }
});
```

When I run this on a browser using my `register.php` file it gives the following error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function
    at Connection.connect (bundle.js:34538)
    at HTMLInputElement.check_Register (bundle.js:43660)
connect @ bundle.js:34538
check_Register @ bundle.js:43660
```

However when I run this in CMD using `node signUp.js` is works perfectly and data goes to the table on the `phpmyadmin`.

I know this is caused by this reason in the provided [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js#:~:text=createConnection%20not%20being%20a%20function,it%20in%20a%20web%20browser.): *"You must run this particular module on Node.js only, you can't run it in a web browser."*

**MY QUESTION:**

Is there any possible way to run this on browser so that users when accessing the `register.php` site could register? Do I need to change the entire structure of my code? Do I need `require('http')` to set a Node.js server?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, I solved this by indeed creating a node.js server. To do this I used the terminal within Visual Studio Code (CMD will also work).

```
cd directoryOfTheApplication //(change the directory of the terminal)
npm init   //(creates a package.json file within directory of the application)
npm install express //(modifies the package.json and add modules within node-modules folder)
```

create a new .js file in the directory (I called mine `server.js`).

```
//USE `nodemon scripts/server.js` on Terminal to autosave the server files.

//My modules
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan"); //GET INFORMATION ABOUT THE SERVER REQUESTS (OS, Browser,time, ...)
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('combined')); //'short', 'combined'

app.get("/users/:id", (req, res) => {

    const userID = req.params.id;
    console.log("Fetching user with id : " + userID); 

    //get data from DB
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "admin1",
        password: "secret",
        database: "myDB"
    });
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM student_demographics WHERE id =?";
    connection.query(sql, [userID], (err, rows, fields) => {
        console.log("Fetching users was successful");
        res.json(rows);
    });

    //res.end();
});

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("responding to root route");
    res.send("hello world from root");
});

app.get("/users", (req, res)=>{
    const user1 = {
        firstName: "name1",
        lastName: "name2"
    };
    const user2 = {
        firstName: "name3",
        lastName: "name4"
    };
    res.json([user1, user2]);
});

app.listen(81, ()=>{
    console.log("Server running on port 81");
});
```

Once again in terminal, you may wish to install `nodemon` so that you don't have to start the server manually. This will refresh and update the server when saving the file (in this case `server.js`). Also `morgan` will basically collect information regarding the request of the user. In terminal it would look like this:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mymindmapper> nodemon scripts/server.js
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node scripts/server.js`
Server running on port 81
Fetching user with id : 1
Fetching users was successful
::1 - - [14/Jun/2020:11:15:20 +0000] "GET /users/1 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 
Safari/537.36"
```

The other module `mysql` is for the sake of this example, but I guess it would work with any modules. I basically followed the tutorials of this brilliant person on YT.

Setup express: [NodeJS REST API: Super Simple Setup - Express & NPM (Ep1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7NVpxxmmgM)

Setup DB:   [NodeJS REST API: Connecting to MySQL (Ep 2)](https://youtu.be/mLLUqMpf5H0)