# Net.createConnection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a problem when I am trying to connect my project to PHPMYADMIN

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "edu_app",
    port: "3306"

});
con.connect();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005968/error-in-mysql-library-for-node-js

Comment: i didnt understand what should i do ?

Comment: you can't run mysql library in browser (directly in vue code), you have to create some api that will connect to database and expose data.

Comment: https://bezkoder.com/node-js-rest-api-express-mysql/

Comment: Where are you attempting to run this code?  In a browser or in nodejs?  That fact that you tagged it vue.js makes me think you're bundling this code and trying to run it in the front-end and the error you're getting sounds like there is no `net` module which would also be consistent with trying to run it in the front-end.  You can't run mysql in the front-end.  It only runs in the back-end.

Comment: And, you would never want to be providing your database password to the front-end code either.

Comment: @jfriend00 password ? :P

Comment: I think vue.js does not have to do any thing here. So you could remove the vue.js tag.

Comment: @VikumDheemantha you have and don't have right :). because for shure more juniors will try to connect to database from vue and others frontend frameworks. So if is tagged vue it can help more people.

Comment: @Robert yep, I forgot there is that kind of possibility.